# Не запускается сервер на питоне

Tags: python, http

win 7. python2.7

печатаю в терминале:
python -m SimpleHTTPserver 8000

ошибка: 
C:\Python327\python.exe: No module named SimpleHTTPserver

почему? что не так?

Answer (score 1):

Два варианта - либо просто неверно написали  (регистр символа `S`)

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

либо у Вас модуля на самом деле нет (а сюда скопировали неверно). В этом случае поможет easy_install.

Comment: да это, вроде, ж модуль из стандартной библиотеки

Comment: модуль есть! это модуль из СБ.
печатаю в idle : 
>>> import SimpleHTTPServer
>>>